# Testing client side validation with cucumber, capybara and webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara-webkit

I am using Cucumber along with Capybara for integration testing in my application.

I have a `Scenario` setup like this

```
  @javascript
  Scenario: Register with invalid values with javascript validation
    Given I am not signed in
    When I register with an invalid account
    Then I should see "Please enter a valid email address."
    And I should see "Please enter a strong password with a minimum of 8 charaters."
    And I should see "The password confirmation does not match the entered password."
    And I should be on the sign up page
```

The form has validation provided through Abide (Zurb Foundation). While in the browser the validations work fine, the same goes when I am using the Selenium web-driver with Chrome.

However, I would like to run the tests headless using the Capybara webkit driver. When I set the driver as the default using `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit` (I have the `capybara-webkit` gem installed). The JavaScript validation fails to prevent the form from submitting.

Here is my step definition for `When I register with an invalid account`

```
When(/^I register with an invalid account$/) do
  visit new_member_registration_path
  fill_in "Email", :with => "test@"
  fill_in "member[password]", :with => "test"
  fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => "testt"
  click_button "Sign up"
end
```

Is there something else I need to enable to test the client side validation?

Comment: Does the scenario pass if you `sleep 5` between filling in the last field and clicking "Sign up"?

Comment: I just tried this, and no. I am still receiving the same result.